# How to send child page value to parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pages parent page and child page, I have to add the selected value from child page to parent page. The below is my code for parent page.

```
 function lookup(){
        window.open('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/accountpopup','popuppage','width=400,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=400,top=100,left=100');

}

 function updateValue(param)
{
    document.getElementById("name").value = param;
}
```

And below is my child/popup page code:

```
 function callaccount(param){
    var parent1=window.dialogAruments;
    var v=param;
     parent1.updateValue(param);
     window.close();
    }
```

the popup is not closing and sending values to parent page

Comment: I think there is no connection between the two pages after opening.   
You can send this parameter with url: ?param=value, but this way you need to update server side code

Comment: I am able to get parameter but while sending to the parent page its not going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.opener`. Please note that there are other functions in window like `window.open`, `window.self`, `window.top` and `window.parent`.
But in your case, window.opener is more relevant, because it refers to the window which called `window.open(...)`
So, your function should be:

```
function callaccount(param){
    var parent1=window.dialogAruments;
    var v=param;
     window.opener.updateValue(param);
     window.close();
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery local storage

Your code should look like this page1 where you want to pass value:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("variable", "value");
}
else {
    console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}
```

Your page2 where you need that data:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Retrieve
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("variable"));
}
else {
    console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}
```

View output in `console`, and let me know it will helps you or not !

Answer (score 0):

### Use window.opener

You need to use [window.opener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) as below in you child page.

```
childWindow.opener.document.getElementById('<id from parent form>').value = '123';
```

The opener property returns a reference to the window that created the window.

When opening a window with the window.open() method, you can use this property from the child window to return details of the parent window.